# Fork and return without waiting for child in perl

Tags: linux, perl, fork, cgi

I have a perl CGI program that uses `fork()` to launch a child process. The child does some long-running (~60 second) calculations and eventually saves the results in a tmp file. The parent is supposed to return control to the browser, which displays a progress message and checks periodically whether the child has written its tmp file; once the file appears, the results are displayed.  So the code looks like this:

```
# Get a unique name for this job
my $guid = Data::GUID->new;
my $id = $guid->as_hex;

# Do the fork 
my $pid = fork;
if (!defined $pid) {
    die "cannot fork: $!";

# Child does this
} elsif ($pid == 0) {
    # Do some calculations
    # Save results in a filename with $id

# Parent does this 
} else {
    # Return the location of the tmp files to the client
    return "Content-Type: text/html\n\n", $id;
    # Browser uses contents of $id to check for the result file
}
```

I originally set this up on RedHat Linux, and it worked just fine.  However, now I'm trying to port it to a server running Ubuntu, and it seems that the parent is waiting for the long-running child to finish before it returns. I believe this to be the case because the browser hangs for the duration of the calculation, never shows the progress page, and immediately jumps to the results once the calculation is done.

I suspect this has something to do with fork emulation, but I'm not certain, and I haven't been able to find a way around it.  Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT: This code is part of a subroutine - I use CGI::Application, so the calling code just "uses" this code. Hence the return statement.  I doubt this accounts for the problem, though, because I haven't touched the code since porting from Red Hat (where it worked) to Linux (where it doesn't).

Comment: `fork()` is a POSIX thing, and shouldn't change between platforms. I'm also pretty sure neither platform will be emulating it. Your problem is likely something else. I would guess buffering on either the web server or client.

Comment: @Sobrique: *"`fork()` is a POSIX thing, and shouldn't change between platforms"* That assumes a *very* limited concept of "platforms"!

Comment: @danny: You have a `return` in there, so this is (part of) a subroutine? I think you need to show the calling code. You should take a look at [`perldoc -q 'How do I fork a daemon process?'`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-fork-a-daemon-process%3f)

Comment: @Borodin when the OP is talking about different variants of Linux, then that's a safe assumption.

Comment: @Sobrique: I agree, but I still think your comment is oddly general. There is no guarantee that people will read your comment in context, and I would much prefer *"shouldn't be different across those platforms"* or *"shouldn't change across flavours of Linux"*.

Comment: Re "*it seems that the parent is waiting for the long-running child to finish before it returns*", How did you arrive to that conclusion?

Comment: In the code you show the parent is not going to wait for anything.  After the `fork`, there are _two processes_ running down the code; one gets into `$pid==0` branch, the other into `else`, and they both keep going.  There is no reason for the parent to "wait."  If this is in a sub (otherwise you'd get a warning for `return`, with `use warnings;` on) it will return around the same time as the child is just starting up.  I'd guess that something else, likely with the server, isn't "porting" right.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't "_emulate_" `fork`, but [`fork`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html) "_Does a fork(2) system call to create a new process ..._" since the "_fork(2) system call_" is available.

Comment: @Borodin, ikegami: see my edits that answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Randal Schwartz's [Watching long processes through CGI](http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/LinuxMag/col39.html) provides a useful example. It is straightforward to fork:

```
if ( my $pid = fork ) {       # parent does

    delete_all();             # clear parameters
    param( 'session', $session );
    print redirect( self_url() );
}
elsif ( defined $pid ) {    # child does

    close STDOUT;           # so parent can go on

    unless ( open F, "-|" ) {

        open STDERR, ">&=1";
        exec "/usr/sbin/traceroute", $host;
        die "Cannot execute traceroute: $!";
    }
```

The rest of the article explains how to help the user keep track of a running job.